# Best way to store images to sqlite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

## What is the best way to store images to database?

### *From Gallery/Camera image to SQLiteDB

- Converting image to byte[] and store it as BLOB or
- Get the image path and store it as string

Comment: the best way is to store the `Uri` taken from the Gallery / Camera

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to store them on disk on a folder and store it's folder path in the database. If you don't have a database, you can convert the image's byte-array to Base64 (Base64 encode) and when you want to show it, decode from Base64 to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that, convert images to base 64 and then store in database and during retrieval convert base64 to bitmap and show.